# Pure JS equivalent of Jquery eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the pure equivalent of jquery's `eq()`. For example, how may I achieve

```
$(".class1.class2").eq(0).text(1254);
```

in pure javascript?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To get the element index in the array you can use `[]` in javascript. So to reproduce your code you can use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class1.class2')[0].textContent = 1254;
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class1.class2')[0].innerHTML = 1254;
```

- In your example `1254` is a number, if you have a string you should use `= 'string';` with quotes.
- If you are only looking for one/the first element you can use just `.querySelector()` insteal of `.querySelectorAll()`.

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2JEP7/)**

**More reading:**

> MDN: [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)
>   MDN: [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)
>   MDN: [querySelectorAll](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll.html)

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` returns an array, so you can get the element `0` using index

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class1.class2")[0].innerHTML = 1254
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to achieve it. Tested working! It splits up the string you want to select into the parts before the `:eq` and after the `:eq`, and then runs them separately. It repeats until there's no more `:eq` left.

```
var querySelectorAllWithEq = function(selector, document) {
  var remainingSelector = selector;
  var baseElement = document;
  var firstEqIndex = remainingSelector.indexOf(':eq(');

  while (firstEqIndex !== -1) {
    var leftSelector = remainingSelector.substring(0, firstEqIndex);
    var rightBracketIndex = remainingSelector.indexOf(')', firstEqIndex);
    var eqNum = remainingSelector.substring(firstEqIndex + 4, rightBracketIndex);
    eqNum = parseInt(eqNum, 10);

    var selectedElements = baseElement.querySelectorAll(leftSelector);
    if (eqNum >= selectedElements.length) {
      return [];
    }
    baseElement = selectedElements[eqNum];

    remainingSelector = remainingSelector.substring(rightBracketIndex + 1).trim();
    // Note - for now we just ignore direct descendants:
    // 'a:eq(0) > i' gets transformed into 'a:eq(0) i'; we could maybe use :scope
    // to fix this later but support is iffy
    if (remainingSelector.charAt(0) === '>') {
      remainingSelector = remainingSelector.substring(1).trim();
    }

    firstEqIndex = remainingSelector.indexOf(':eq(');
  }

  if (remainingSelector !== '') {
    return Array.from(baseElement.querySelectorAll(remainingSelector));
  }

  return [baseElement];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class1.class2")[0].innerHTML = '1254';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Element.querySelectorAll**

Summary

Returns a non-live NodeList of all elements descended from the element on which it is invoked that match the specified group of CSS selectors.

Syntax

```
elementList = baseElement.querySelectorAll(selectors);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only getting the first one, `document.querySelector(".class1.class2")` will suffice. It returns the element itself, and doesn't have to build an entire node list just to get the first.

However, if you want anything other than the first, then you will need `querySelectorAll`.