# Vanilla JS equivalent to $(nav ul li a).eq[0].attr('href')

Tags: javascript, html

What is the Vanilla JS equivalent to the Jquery code written above? In a html page, if those a link href's are actually Id's of elements on the same page, said code will return the actual element object.

something like

```
document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a')[0].getAttribute('href')
```

will only return the value of the href as a string: not the element that it's linking to.

How can I achieve this in Vanilla, plain Javascript? Is there actually a way to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure JS equivalent of Jquery eq()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930975/pure-js-equivalent-of-jquery-eq)

Comment: @Ikillnukes No, I'm not inquiring about .eq(). Please understand what the question is actually asking about before commenting: I'm inquiring about How JQuery's .attr('href') function works and its equivalent in pure javascript. I described that in the description.

Comment: Well, getting this is more resource expensive, because you have to iterate over ALL the nodes and subnodes of the document and search for one that has the required href attribute value.

Comment: Perhaps: but one; doesn't JQuery's attr.('href') function work the same way? and Two: is there truly no way to do the same in plain JS?

Comment: @cpsavante `.attr('href')` just returns the string, not the element.

Comment: If you want to get the element itself, you have to wrap it in `$()`: `$($(nav ul li a).eq[0].attr('href'))`. You can do the same thing with `document.querySelector`.

Comment: BTW, if you just want the first matched element, use `document.querySelector(...)` instead of `document.querySelectorAll(...)[0]`.

Comment: @Barmar wrapping .getAttribute('href') within document.querySelector is returning the link element itself, as opposed to the element that the link is referencing. With this, atleast, I'm one step closer now

Comment: I don't see how that could be. If `getAttribute("href")` returns something like `#someID`, it's the same as doing `document.querySelector('#someID')`.

Comment: WHOOPS! Nevermind xD It appears that it may just be getting way too late for me. Double checked the console and yes, your suggestion actually did work as intended. Thank you so much for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value of the `href` is something like `#someID`, and you want to get the element that this refers to, use:

```
var element = document.querySelector(document.querySelector('nav ul li a').getAttribute('href'));
```

or to make the code clearer:

```
var selector = document.querySelector('nav ul li a').getAttribute('href');
var element = document.querySelector(selector);
```